# More clarity on Verilog Non-Blocking assignments

Tags: verilog

Consider HDL code below:

```
module top_module ();

reg [2:0] a, b, c;

initial begin
   a = 3'b001; b = 3'b010; c = 3'b011; 
end

initial begin
    #5 $display ("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d", a, b, c);
end

initial begin
    a <= b;
    b <= c;
    // b <= a;
    $display ("a = %d, b = %d, c = %d", a, b, c);
    #50 $finish;            // Quit the simulation
end    
endmodule
```

The output is:

```
Running Icarus Verilog simulator...
a = 1, b = 2, c = 3
VCD info: dumping is suppressed.
a = 2, b = 3, c = 3
Hint: Total mismatched samples is 0 out of 0 samples

Simulation finished at 50 ps
Mismatches: 0 in 0 samples
```

In the above code:
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) initially:
Scene-1:

```
a <= b;
b <= c;
```

I get: a = 2, b = 3, c = 3; Hence initial, un-updated value of b.
(a = 1, b = 2, c = 3) initially:

Scene-2:

```
a <= b;
b <= c;
a <= c;
```

I get: a = 3, b = 3, c = 3;

Even more, if I do this:

Scene-3:

```
a <= b;
b <= c;
a <= b;
```

then too I get: a = 2, b = 3, c = 3;

In scene-1 and 3, **a** is getting the value as per the older assignment of **b**, but in scene-2, **it** is getting the latest value as per the latest assignment of **c**. I'm trying to wrap my head around this, need to get better understanding of this.

Comment: Here's how I think of it: there is a "current" state and a "next" state. When you write `a <= b;`, you're not changing `a`, you're saying "the next value of a will be the current value of b". If then you write `a <= c;`, it's like you've changed your mind and would rather have the next value of a be the current value of c instead. Only when the next tick happens (in your scenario) do the values actually change - and they take up whatever the last assignment you wrote say they should.

Comment: @Mat I love this convention and I'll keep it in mind! BTW this comment is as powerful as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, your code has a race condition at time 0. There is no guarantee that the first `initial` block executes before the third `initial` block. The second `initial` block will guarantee to execute the `$display` statement last because of the `#5` delay.

Non-blocking assignments evaluate the RHS of the assignment at the point in time when the statement gets executed, and the updates to the LHS get scheduled for a later region of time. So the values used on the RHS for a, b, and c will either be 1, 2, and 3, or all X's. By sheer luck, **iverilog** chooses to execute `initial` blocks in the order they appear in the source. This gets much harder to manage when there are multiple instances of multiple modules.

When you have multiple non-blocking assignments to the same variable, last assignment wins. In scene-2, you assign the old value of `b` to `a`, then you assign the old value of `c` to `a`. So `a` gets updated with the old value of `c`.